# Warning unused variable in Haskell code

Tags: haskell

[Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html) says "Haskell compiler can warn us if we introduce a variable name in a pattern, but do not use it in a function's body".

I often forget to use variables which I bind, so I want to use this feature. But my ghci and ghc seem to be fine with unused variables, and I actually have never seen this since I started learning Haskell a few months ago.

How can I use this feature? Or Haskell compiler does not have this feature anymore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As said before, the option is `-fwarn-unused-binds` or `-Wall` for all warnings. Another one is `-Werror` to make the warnings stop the compilation.

To use them, you pass them to `ghc` or `ghci` on the command-line. Additionally, during a session in ghci, you can type

```
:set -fwarn-unused-binds
```

With `cabal` you can add `ghc-options` to the executable section. For instance :

```
executable my-program
  main-is:        MyProgram.hs
  hs-source-dirs: src
  ghc-options:    -Wall
```

Now, running `cabal configure && cabal build` (and other commands) will use the `-Wall` option.

Answer (score 6):

You can look at [Warnings](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html). I generally use `-Wall` in my projects which shows unused binded variables along with several other useful warnings. There is specific flag (`-fwarn-unused-binds`) too to do just what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the `-fwarn-unused-binds` flag to `ghc` or `ghci`. To enable other useful warnings, use `-W`. To enable all warnings, use `-Wall`. For example:

```
ghci -fwarn-unused-binds
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to add flag when compiling with `ghc` but I do not know how to do that with `ghci`. Is there any specific command?

Comment: Start `ghci` with the command as in my example. You can also type e.g. `:set -fwarn-unused-binds` at the ghci command line.